# How to change the type of a variable in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to convert the type of a variable to character:

Data frame is included in the following package.

```
library(pwt10)
```

And I tried the following to figure out the type of the variable:

```
typeof(pwt10.0$isocode)
```

But this generates `[1] "integer"`, which I don't understand because isocode is country id (eg. USA, GER, CAN,....)

Anyhow I try to convert the variable into character using `as.character(pwt10.0$isocode)`.
But after running this code, `typeof(pwt10.0$isocode)` still generates `[1] "integer"`.

I don't understand what's going on here and wonder how to convert it into genuinely a character variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to check the `class` instead of `typeof` as the `typeof` will be `integer` when the `class` is `factor` as that is the storage mode

```
library(pwt10)
data("pwt10.0")
class(pwt10.0$isocode)
[1] "factor"
```

Also, if we want to know the overall picture of the data, check the `str`

```
> str(pwt10.0)
'data.frame':   12810 obs. of  52 variables:
 $ country  : Factor w/ 183 levels "Aruba","Angola",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ isocode  : Factor w/ 183 levels "ABW","AGO","AIA",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ year     : int  1950 1951 1952 1953 1954 1955 1956 1957 1958 1959 ...
 $ currency : Factor w/ 136 levels "Algerian Dinar",..: 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
 $ rgdpe    : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ rgdpo    : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ pop      : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ emp      : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ avh      : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ hc       : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ ccon     : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ cda      : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ cgdpe    : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ cgdpo    : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ cn       : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ ck       : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ ctfp     : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ cwtfp    : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ rgdpna   : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ rconna   : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ rdana    : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ rnna     : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ rkna     : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ rtfpna   : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ rwtfpna  : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ labsh    : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ irr      : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ delta    : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ xr       : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ pl_con   : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ pl_da    : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ pl_gdpo  : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ i_cig    : Factor w/ 5 levels "extrapolated",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ i_xm     : Factor w/ 3 levels "extrapolated",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ i_xr     : Factor w/ 2 levels "market","estimated": NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ i_outlier: Factor w/ 2 levels "no","yes": NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ i_irr    : Factor w/ 4 levels "regular","lowcapital",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ cor_exp  : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ statcap  : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ csh_c    : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ csh_i    : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ csh_g    : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ csh_x    : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ csh_m    : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ csh_r    : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ pl_c     : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ pl_i     : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ pl_g     : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ pl_x     : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ pl_m     : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ pl_n     : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ pl_k     : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

---

Regarding conversion to `character`, the code with `as.character` is correct, but, it should be assigned back to the same column to reflect those changes

```
pwt10.0$isocode <- as.character(pwt10.0$isocode)
class(pwt10.0$isocode)
#[1] "character"
```